# Breath training to increase your lungs capacity

Tags: cardio, breathing

I was recently tempted by an ad about Airofit. It is a connected device which should help you to improve your breathing capacity.

I don't really know how to call such device? Would it help for hiking? I am 42 and my capacity is not great, since I only hike in late/spring and summer and only do weights lifting in winter. Experience about running and other cardio is also welcome.

Does this kind of devices worse it ? Does it compare to altitude breath training ?

Comment: I think there is merit to this question if you re-word it a little. For instance the "experience [...] is also welcome" doesn't really fit the site, since answers should not be primarily anecdotal. From looking at the device's [own FAQ](https://www.airofit.com/pages/how-it-works) it looks like it's something that restricts oxygen availability which makes you work harder to get it, thereby training your diaphragm and intercostal muscles. If you worded the question to directly ask if there is merit to this type of device, it would be more suitable. And I'd also be interested to learn about it.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question, I also like to know if it's compare to altitude breath training

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been some research done that you cannot train lung capacity with a breathing mask or apparatus that works by simply restricting airflow, you can improve pulmonary muscles but not increase oxygen capabilities, breathing abilities or lung capacity. Now the airofit is new and designed  differently, but it is proven that you can't improve lung function or breathing, but perhaps lung capacity is a different story, there is not enough research yet at this time... that being said -

You can train your lung capacity(ability to hold more air in) by using free exercises such as diaphragmatic breathing and more. You really don't need an expensive breathing straw to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you may also now if it's compare to altitude breath training ?

Comment: @Jimbot - The general consensus is that you can't increase capacity. And the masks that claim to mimic high altitude are also pretty bogus. They may help train the muscles, but true altitude adaptations only come from being at altitude, or spending a lot of time living in an altitude tent or similar.

Comment: "There's been some research done" and "it is proven that". Can you add some sources on this? Just for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

*Airofit* is just like any other app or machine which may or may not help you in increasing your stability endurance. Of what I know about *Airofit*, it will help you in incresing your lung capacity, but I do not recommend you to use it. I prefer  the hiking and weight lifting that you do, as it does not concentrate only in lung capacity but also your stability and strength. And exercise also keeps you motivated every day.